# How can I view the terminal execution log of chkdsk when ran at boot time?

Tags: windows-8, boot, chkdsk

If I issue `chkdsk /R` on a removable drive, I get a nice execution status report with a few stats such as an ETA.

[image: enter link description here]

When I want to do the same on my system drive, however, I must reboot and, in order to be user friendly, all Windows tells me is

> ### Scanning and repairing drive (C:): 16% complete

How can I go behind this user friendly façade and see the terminal output in all of its glory?

Comment: Is your question for windows 8?

Comment: @sunk818 I do not expect the answer to be significantly different for Windows 7 or Windows TP.

Comment: You mean windows 10 technical preview? Perhaps not but it's good to be specific for many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an easier way, but you can see the chkdsk verbose logging if you boot from a different drive. You are not able to run chkdsk /r because you can not dismount the system drive.

Edit: now that you've told me what windows OS this is for, windows 8 has /v that will tell you which file is being checked at the current time.